# How to recognize a fake laptop

Tags: laptop

Is there any way to determine if a laptop is original or not?

Comment: Original in what way?, please give more detail to your question.

Comment: Are you talking about a counterfeit with cheap components?

Comment: After or before you buy it?

Comment: Look for keyboard keys glued to the inside of a white binder.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

check the back of your laptop, there's got to be some kind of identification, service tag, serial number or something. then you could try to check on the producer's site if they offer support for your tag.

For example, my Dell Precision has a Service Tag on it's back, and when I go to get drivers from their site, i can either pick a model, or enter the service tag.

Another solution is to call the producer and ask if they have your serial number in the database.

Can't think of another solution, hope these ideas help

Answer (score 1):

Assuming by 'fake laptop' you mean that it has fake specifications when sold, you could check either by validating the components by hand, or booting into an operating system that you know has not been tampered with, and checking what is listed. (`devmgmt.msc`, `lspci`, `lsusb`, `lshw`, etc).

Comment: The BIOS will often show basic info as well, but if the laptop has counterfeit components, the BIOS may have been tampered with, too.

Comment: how do I know if they did something with the BIOS?